# SSAS MDX: Calculated member doesn't show up in Excel

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2016

I created the calculated member as described below in SSMS (not VS, therefore I did not deploy it) by selecting the command and executing it. Accessing this member in MDX works out fine. 
But Excel doesn't show me this measure, and I also do not see it in the cube browser. I expect to find it below the measure groups.

Question: What did I miss?

Additional question: How can I place this measure in a measure group?

```
CREATE MEMBER [Logistics].[Measures].[Printed] AS 
    SUM
    ( 
        {
            (
                [Pick].[Pick Method].&[4]
                , EXCEPT([Pick].[Pick Type].MEMBERS, [Pick].[Pick Type].&[A])
                , EXCEPT([Loc].[Build Zone].MEMBERS, {[Loc].[Build Zone].[All], [Loc].[Build Zone].&[G1], [Loc].[Build Zone].&[G2], [Loc].[Build Zone].&[G3]})
                , EXCEPT([Loc].[Loc Code].MEMBERS, {[Loc].[Loc Code].[All], [Loc].[Loc Code].[EXPRESS]})
            )
        }
        , [Measures].[Nb of Pick lines]
    ) ;
```

Executing this using this MDX-SELECT works out fine and returns a sensible result:

```
SELECT 
        NON EMPTY
        {
            [Location].[Build Zone].MEMBERS, [Location].[Build].[Tested]
        } ON COLUMNS
            , NON EMPTY {[Calendar].[Calendar Year].[Month].&[2019]&[August].children} ON ROWS  
    FROM [Logistics] ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS you can only create Session-scoped calculated members, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/mdx/mdx-calculated-members-session-scoped-calculated-members?view=asallproducts-allversions)

And what you did is that you successfully created this member, and in the same query window if you run this query:

```
select measures.allmembers on 0
from [Logistics]
```

you will actually see `[Measures].[Printed]` member. But as soon as you open a New Query window in SSMS on this cube, and run     `select measures.allmembers on 0  from [Logistics]` again, you will not see your calculated member anymore.

So, the solution is to add this `create member` script in the Calculation Script in Visual Studio, as you mentioned, and to deploy the cube.

Additionally, to place a measure in measure group, or in some folder under it you can use `ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP` and `DISPLAY_FOLDER` properties. So something like this:

```
create member [MyCube].Measures.MyMeasure as 999, ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'My measure group', DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'My display folder'
```

Comment: You helped me a lot: Great, and thank you very much! 

I still have the problem that even if I define the calculated member in Excel it does not return values.

Comment: I already suspected that it was a scope issue but got confused by the fact that even with a definition in Excel I do not get values for Pickings back.

But now I will follow your proposal; if I come up with interesting findings I will report back.
Thanks!